Self contained program asking to install dotnet
When trying to run my program on a different computer it does not run and/or asks for .NET installation even if the program was published as self-contained.
I've tried to share a program with some people, first the program wouldn't do anything when trying to publish from Visual Studio.
Used the solution from (doing it from terminal):
Create Self Contained Single exe File From C# WPF Application
Now the self contained program asks for .NET to be installed
Tried the solution from:
dotnet publish --self-contained -> running the app still asks for .net installation
And now is asking for a different .NET version and the link to said version is just &gui=true, so it does nothing
My questions are:

Is there a difference between publishing from VS and the terminal?
Is there a way I can publish in a way that I get a single .exe that does not ask for global .NET installation ? and how ?

